# How to map a DNS with an IP address?

Tags: tomcat, dns, ip, hosting

I dont know if i asked the question correctly but here is my situation:

I have a web site **www.mywebsite.com** which is using a commercial hosting. The website is static. I want to make it dynamic but i want to use my own server with tomcat.

So lets say the application is on my webserver and can be accessed as:

**http://aaa.bbb.ccc.dddd:8084/MyApplication**

So the question is:

How can i make it that when the user enters ***www.mywebsite.com*** to be loaded the application that i host at ***http://aaa.bbb.ccc.dddd:8084/MyApplication*** ?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to achieve this including, but not limited to:

1. Proxying (for instance [mod_proxy in an Apache VHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#proxy))
2. Redirecting (for instance using [mod_rewrite in an Apache VHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html))
3. [Tomcat VHosts](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html)

There are also many web servers you can use to achieve this, but a very fairly common approach is to set up [Apache Web Server](http://httpd.apache.org/) and use the [Apache Tomcat Connectors](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/quick.html). Essentially, this is putting Apache in front of Tomcat and allowing Tomcat to handle certain requests based on configuration.

No matter what route you take, you'll have to point DNS (for your chosen domain) to your Web Server or whatever you are using as your Web Server.

Comment: A mixed choice of proxying and redirecting is the best way to make it work: <VirtualHost *:8080>
 
 ServerName sub.domain.com
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass / https://192.168.1.23:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.1.23:8080/
 
</VirtualHost>. Everytime I access my server using https://sub.domain.com:8080 I get redirected to the desired page.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. DNS has absolutely NOTHING to do with HTTP, other than providing a hostname<->ip mapping. You cannot force a port with DNS, you cannot force a particular path on a site with dns, you can't even redirect with DNS.

Your only option is to put up a virtualhost for `www.mywebsite.com` and redirect the user to the "real" address, e.g.

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    Redirect Permanent / http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:8084/MyApplication
</virtualhost>
```

If you don't want the users to see that `:8084` business, then'd you need to turn your `mywebsite.com` "site" into a transparent proxy.

Comment: So i dont need to change any dns setting in the host panel

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest to setup proxy on your server.
Update A record for www.mywebsite.com to aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd, then run proxy on your server.

In case of apache,

```
<VirtualHost aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:80>

  ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8084/MyApplication
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8084/MyApplication

</VirtualHost>
```

Something like this would work?